# Number of connected component of a quotient space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, real-algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand the number of connected components of an algebraic variety $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by the system of $m$ polynomial equations and $n>m>1$. The system of equations is defined as follows:

Given $m$ constants $u_k \in \mathbb{R}$, and positive integers $d_k \geq 3 $, $k=1,\cdots,m$,

$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{d_k} = u_k  
$, $k=1,\cdots,m$.

Note that the equations are invariant under the action of the symmetric group $S_m$. Hence the number of connected component is at most $c \cdot m!$, where $c$ is the number of connected components of the quotient space $V/S_n$.

My question is: how to prove or disprove that the number of connected components of $V/S_n$ is independent of $n$,
or 
Does anybody know some reference about the properties of this class of algebraic varieties.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused: If you have $m = 1$ equation $x^{2} = u$ in $n = 1$ variable, the number of components depends on $u$, i.e., is not dependent merely on $n$. Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for this observation. I edited the question by specifying $m>1$.  The idea is that the algebraic variery must have a non-empty interior.